# Login/Register to Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a site and need to make user login. The logged user will be able to download some documents from one of the pages.

I installed some plugins but all of them enable logged users to see dashboard and login goes through wp-admin.

I am a beginner and I have no experience with this. How to make user login but prevent them to see anything from dashboard?

Comment: try this http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-allow-user-registration-on-your-wordpress-site/ http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-custom-login-page-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

try 'user role editer' in wp admin panel.there you can  change/mention the capabilities of particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Front end users is what I am looking. Here is the answer https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-only-users/